# "Relay access denied" error when sending email using CakePHP 1.3

Tags: email, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to send an email using CakePHP 1.3 and I'm getting this error message:

**"SMTP server error: 4.7.1 : Relay access denied"**

The code for sending email is as below:

```
this->set('username',$username);
$this->set('pass',$pass);
$this->Email->fromName = Configure::read('from_team');        
$this->Email->to       = $to;    
$this->Email->subject  = 'New Password';    
$result = $this->Email->send();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to invalid SMTP settings. I have detected it and solved it.